# Standard name values for form's elements?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, microdata, microformats

Recently I've read some Google article about using standard name values for HTML Forms for to help browsers' auto-compile to work better

In this list was included, for example, `name="city"` for user's city, `name="surname"`, etc.

Sadly though I forgot to bookmark that article.

Now I'm updating my forms and I want to improve user's experience, if possible.

Are there (other) standards for Forms' name values? If yes, which should I follow?

What about ARIA?

I'm looking for solutions that are already implemented in UAs, or that are going to be implemented in short-term

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the article you were looking for?

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/making-form-filling-faster-easier-and.html

As far as I know there is no standard for forms name values. the closet attempt would be http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4112.txt but they are horrible and something I personally wouldn't use.

Comment: I think the actual link should be here, too (and not only the link to a blog post about it): http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Autocomplete_Types